# maxmatch algorithm for lexicon based string tokenization without probability

Tags: python

I am trying to implement maxmatch algorithm for lexicon based string tokenization without probability. i have no idea where to start. Anybody has some ideas?

Comment: This is a bit vague. What have you tried?

Comment: def segment(hashtag,dictionary):
    for i in range(1,len(hashtag)+1):
        substr=hashtag[:i]
        if diction.has_key(substr):
            print substr

Answer (score 1):

MaxMatch is already implemented. An example implementation below. You don't need to start from scratch, you can fork the below GitHub repository and enhance as per your requirement.

https://github.com/saurabhsood91/maxmatch

Must do:

- Reference this repository wherever you present your work.
- Write back to the author with the improvements you have implemented.
- Let the community know how your approach is different & better.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a metric to measure a word's distance to one of your tokens. The python library [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) is definitely a good start to help you achieve this.

It is not clear, though, whether you want to match an entire text against keywords (e.g. search terms) or if you just want to match a single word against each word in your lexicon.

In both cases, the difflib docs will probably be helpful.

Comment: '30secondtomars' should produce '30 second to mars'.

Comment: I've been workin on d following algo: 
1.start pointer at beginning of string. 
2.Find longest word in dictionary that matches starting at pointer.If no match,emit character & advance pointer by 1 character. 
3. move pointer over the word inn string. 
4. go to step2